# Adding custom command in client class

Tags: python, python-decorators, discord.py

Using the Discord API i often saw this: @client. My first question is how do you call these? I only I only knew @overwrite before and toughed this has just optical reasons.

I do not really know how they worked which brings me to my main question:

How to use this @ things in a costume client class:

```
class CoustumeClient(discord.Client):
    def __init__(self, **options):
        super().__init__(**options)
        self.bot_channel = []
        self.search_channel = 713078892885442621

    @client.command
    async def ping(self, ctx):
```

does not seem to work

Comment: If you are looking to create a discord bot then use the `discord.ext.commands.Bot` object.

Comment: All your questions pertain solely to **decorators** not discord.py itself. Here is a quick tutorial: https://realpython.com/primer-on-python-decorators/

Comment: @JoshuaNixon While I agree that the the extensions for discord.py are very useful for creating a bot, they are entirely optional. Simple bots do not need to use discord.ext.

But it is true that the ```command``` functionality is something built into the extensions, not the base discord.py library.

Comment: Also, there is a Discord API help server which you can join here - https://discord.gg/discord-api

Comment: But i still have one question to discord.ext is there a class like discord.Client i can inherit from to get these functionalities. discord.ext also themes to have the task function i need

Comment: @MarcelSchultz Yes there is, it is the bot class: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot

Answer (score 1):

If it's on a class (Cog) `@client.command` won't work, instead use `@commands.command`